# How to use bodyparser in node.js

Tags: node.js

> When do I use bodyparser in my code?

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
app.set('views',__dirname+'/public/pages/');
app.set('view engine','twig');
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.get('/',(req, res)=>{
    res.render('index',{title:"create user"})
})
app.post('/',(req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.body.username);
})
app.listen(8000, ()=>console.log('server is running at:http://localhost:8000'));
```

> when I run this code:Error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc8Cs.jpg)

Comment: I see, you  misspell bodyparser variable name, change it  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })) from app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false })).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have `const bodyparser = require('body-parser');` in lowercase ,then you use it  with camelCase 
`bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })`

Answer (score 0):

There is a spelling mistake just change **bodyparser** to **bodyParser** in second line of your code.

Answer (score 0):

> When do i use bodyparser in my code ?

npm page for the module says, "Node.js body parsing middleware.
Parse incoming request bodies in a middleware before your handlers, available under the req.body property."
read more [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)